# How to add detail button on the last position in each of the table row using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am fetching the JSON file from local in the table, i just want to add the button in last of each row. How can i do this? I was trying but fail to add button in the last position. 2-fedtest.json is my local file that i read the JSON file and show all the data in the table.
[image: Here is the table]

> Code

```
function check_user_online() {

    var logged_in_user = {};
    logged_in_user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('current_login_user')); //get data from storage
    // alert(logged_in_user.img);
    if (logged_in_user == undefined) {
        window.location.href = 'login.html';
    } else {
        var profile_image = logged_in_user.image;
        var email = logged_in_user.email;
        // var user_email = logged_in_user.email;
        document.getElementById('dashboard_image').src = profile_image;
        document.getElementById('Username').innerHTML = 'Welcome, ' + email;

        var myInit = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            mode: 'cors',
            cache: 'default'
        };

        let myRequest = new Request("2-fedtest.json", myInit);

        fetch(myRequest)
            .then(function(resp) {
                return resp.json();
            })
            .then(function(data) {
                console.log(data.listing_data);
                // alert(JSON.stringify(data.listing_data));
                response(data.listing_data);
            })

        function response(e) {
            let table = document.getElementById("transaction_table");
            let row, cell, button;

            for (let i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
                row = table.insertRow();
                cell = row.insertCell();
                cell.textContent = e[i].request_id;
                cell = row.insertCell();
                cell.textContent = e[i].document_last_name;
                cell = row.insertCell();
                cell.textContent = e[i].email;
                cell = row.insertCell();
                cell.textContent = e[i].document_dob;
                cell = row.insertCell();
                cell.textContent = e[i].used_services_in_request;
                cell = row.insertCell();
                cell.textContent = e[i].country_name;
                cell = row.insertCell();
                cell.textContent = e[i].reference;
                cell = row.insertCell();
                cell.textContent = e[i].created_at;
                cell = row.insertCell();
                cell.textContent = e[i].verification_status;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% right about the cell API you are using but you should be able to insert a dom node inside it:

so, you can remove the if statement I've mentioned and after your: 
`cell.textContent = e[i].verification_status;`

you can add:

```js
cell = row.insertCell(); 
const button = document.createElement("button"); 
button.innerHTML = 'your text'; 
button.onclick = function(e){ /*something to handle events*/} 
cell.innerHTML = button
```

Comment: Hi, i am not using any API

Comment: Code you share with me is added only one button in the last row, i want to add buttons in each of the last row

Comment: Sorry I was referring to the Client-side web API. I just edited my answer. I hope it fits you.